# Bash Script to do operations based on file extensions where the input is the path to the file. MacOSX

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, nasm

**EDIT2:**
THIS POST IS SOLVED (if you would like to see the product that tis post resulted in please visit the site  http://www.nasmagic.com )

here is my plan firstly

i am using Platypus (http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) a program for OSX that lets you create little "droplets" that basically wrap a bash script in a fancy drag and drop GUI.

now im using this as a nice easy way of making myself a drag and drop Nasm assembler.

i have made a few of these "droplets" with simple bash scripts inside them, one example would be the folowing:-

```
#!/bin/bash

chmod u+x $1
```

this as you can see makes my scripts executable,... very handy.

The way they work is they take one variable only and that is the path to the file eg.

```
/Users/MiRAGE/Desktop/example.sh
```

now here is my conundrum for the day

i need to do the following command:-

```
/usr/local/bin/nasm -f macho example.asm && ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -o example example.o
```

this is one command that works fine with the non variable filenames. however in the droplet context it has a problem.

it can execute each of these commands in two seperate droplets but without changing the command it will not find the outputed file of the first command as it is not 'cd'd into the directory where the file is outputed so it doesent know what to do.

now as i say at the moment i have successfully got it to compile with one droplet with this command:-

```
/usr/local/bin/nasm -f macho $1
```

which i drag the file into first and it spits out a ".o" file

then i drop that ".o" file into droplet2 which has this command inside:-

```
ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -lSystem -o $1.5y $1
```

this command is much less elegant than the first.
the only way i could get it to compile the file is to append my made up extention otherwise it would just not work. the problem with this method is that while it does output the compiled binary it ends up looking like this "exampleFilename.o.5y".

now i could go in and delete that and i would, i guess be where i need to be. but its very messy. 2 droplets, renaming files..... not what i want i want a drag and drop hassle free assembler.

so heres the code i have in mind except this is not real and clearly doesn't work.

```
if [filename $1 == ".asm"]                            # if the file extension is ".asm" 
then                                                  # then do next step 
/usr/local/bin/nasm -f macho $1                       # make mach-o file
fi                                                    # end
else if [filename $1 == ".o"]                         # else if the file extension is ".o" 
then                                                  # then do this step
ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -lSystem -o $1 $1.o     # take the file ".o" and outfile with no extention but the same name.
fi                                                    #end
```

this way i can drag it in once, it will spit out the ".o" file, then i drag that in, and it then converts it to the executable binary. PERFECT
but i cant for the life of me find out how to write this properly if anyone can help i would be very very appreciative

many thanks in advance

**MiRAGE**

Comment: Do you need to know how to check for a file extension in bash???

Comment: yes but i need to know how to check for it and then do operations based on which filetype is imported else/if style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to be able to drag the .asm file to the droplet, then drag the resulting .o file to the droplet to produce an executable, in two steps.

In which case, after downloading platypus and recent nasm, I find this script works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the path to the input file, and enter that directory
pathname=$(dirname "$1")
cd $pathname
# attempt strip the .asm extension off the input filename (if there is one)
filestem=$(basename -s .asm "$1")
# If the input file was a .asm file, then assemble it:
if [ "${pathname}/${filestem}.asm" == "$1" ]; then
    /usr/local/bin/nasm -f macho "$1"
fi
# attempt strip the .o extension off the input filename (if there is one)
filestem=$(basename -s .o "$1")
# If the input file was a .o file, then link it:
if [ "${pathname}/${filestem}.o" == "$1" ]; then
    ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -o "$filestem" "$1"
fi
```

This script takes care to make sure output files are placed into the same directory as the input files.

---

Conversely, if you want a script to assemble and link in one shot, this works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the path to the input file, and enter that directory
pathname=$(dirname "$1")
cd $pathname
# attempt strip the .asm extension off the input filename (if there is one)
filestem=$(basename -s .asm "$1")
# If the input file was an .asm file, then assemble and link it:
if [ "${pathname}/${filestem}.asm" == "$1" ]; then
    /usr/local/bin/nasm -f macho "$1" && ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -o "${pathname}/$filestem" "${pathname}/${filestem}.o"
fi
```

Note that what you have here basically replicates a lot of [make](/questions/tagged/make) or similar build systems do for you.

Note also that third-party software like playtpus is not strictly needed for the drag-n-drop part.  You can use the built-in automator application to create similar applications.  e.g I created one that you just drag example.asm onto the automator application icon and it runs the same shell script for you.

Also, you can test the shell script at the command line, simply by calling:

```
./myscript.sh example.asm
```

or

```
./myscript.sh example.o
```

Comment: this works up until the && it will do the first command and output the .o file but the linking step doesn't execute.

i was going to do it in 2 steps so i need to break that into the if/else statement i explained above, so i can drag the .o file in and perform the linking step.

thanks for your help

Comment: How does it fail?  Is example.o produced?  Are there any errors/warnings from nasm or ld?  Can you run the script from the terminal?

Comment: I noticed I missed `-lSystem` from the `ld` command in my answer.  I have edited the answer to include this.

Comment: hi there 
the script wont run in terminal because it does not get a chance to take arguments i get

    nasm: error: no input file specified
    type `nasm -h' for help
    logout

Comment: the wrapper runs the script once on start and it will fail because there are no arguments, then it waits for a dragged file as its argument.
this script when in the wrapper does produce exmpl.o but it does'nt link it
so i need to be able to either get it to link it first time round or 2 be able to drag the exmpl.o back into th patch, nd have the patch recognise its not a .asm file nd do th linking instead of th macho creation

Comment: @MiRAGE - I considerably revised my answer - please check

Comment: basically im gonna say this one is the answer the script works flawlessly in both 32 and 64 bit with some small edits. many many thanks for your help.

could you just walk me through the script so i can understand it aswell as use it :) 

many thanks once again

Comment: Please see the comments added to both versions of the script.  Let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: You truly have enlightened me many thanks @DigitalTrauma. Many many thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ext=${1/*./}
test $ext == "asm" && /usr/local/bin/nasm -f macho "$1"
output=${1/*\//}; output=${output/.*/}
test $ext == "o" && ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -lSystem -o $output $1
```

Comment: this script does produce example.o but does not do the linking, if you could wrap it in an if/ele statement so if you drag in a .asm it will make a macho and if you drag in a .o file it will do the linking it would work to a satisfactory standard, i just dont know how to do that.

Comment: I am not sure where it breaks. Can you execute the script manually from a terminal like this and share the output? `bash -x this_sript  your.asm` and then `bash -x this_sript your.o`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try [make](/questions/tagged/make) to do this, the following will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

target=$(dirname "$1")/$(basename -s ".${1/*./}" "$1")
export CC=ld
export LDFLAGS="-macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -lSystem"
make -f - "$target" <<EOF
%.o: %.asm
    /usr/local/bin/nasm -f macho $<
.PRECIOUS: %.o
EOF
```

*(Note there is a `TAB` character at the start of the `nasm` line.)*

The beauty of using [make](/questions/tagged/make) is that targets are only rebuilt if they don't exist, or they are older than their prerequisites.  Also make has built-in implicit rules for many things, including linking a `.o` to create an executable, which we make use of.

- This script will accept a .asm file or .o file as input, from which it will derive a make target (the name of the expected executable) by stripping off the extension.
- explicitly set the linker to be "ld" instead of the default of "cc"
- set necessary linker flags in the LDFLAGS variable
- call `make` with the derived target.  Normally `make` will parse a `Makefile` for its rules, but in this case, we redirect a makefile using a `bash` here-document.
- The redirected makefile has one implicit rule, which says to assemble x.asm into x.o
- The redirected makefile also has a special `.PRECIOUS` rule, which prevents deletion of intermediate files (.o files in this case)

Comment: this one works very well for 32 bit but usully to compile 64bit asm i just have to add "macho64" instead of "macho" and it would work. i just cant seem to get it to work. as soon as i add the 64 it just wont do anything :/

Comment: when trying to run it in 64 bit in terminal like this:-

/Users/MiRAGE/Desktop/compl64.sh /Users/MiRAGE/Desktop/asm64.TEST/123/1/64.asm

i get the following error:-
 
/var/folders/2h/p0g4rp_n3sl1npc5k9fnn3s00000gn/T/GmqvCkZO:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: Is it possible the `TAB` character at the start of the nasm line got converted to spaces, somehow?